# Is it possible to start ignite cache by only providing the cache configuration in a java client?

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, ignite

I would like to know if I can start a ignite cache from  java client . I am using Cassandra as the persistence store and use POJO configurations to work with the cache and Cassandra. With out providing any named cache configuration in server side is it possible ?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Cache itself can be dynamically started using `Ignite#createCache` method. However, classes that are required for this cache need to be deployed explicitly in advance, before servers are started.

In your case you will have to deploy POJO classes because they are currently required by Cassandra store. You will be able to skip this step though after this ticket is implemented: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5270

Comment: I tried  to start an ignite server  with POJO classes already in server without any cache configuration and when I tried to connect ignite through the java client with cache configuration  an error is thrown with null pointer exception :                           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5439)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5488) Please provide your suggestions...

Comment: Which version of Ignite do you use? How do you load the cache?

Comment: I am using ignite 2.0.0. I started a server with default  configuration. I have provided the POJO as jar file in the sever. In the client java code I have provided the persistence config, data source and the cache configuration. And cache is invoked as   
 Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration); Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();   cache1 = ignite.getOrCreateCache("cache1");  And by the last line the above said error is thrown.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer? Small Maven/Gradle based project on GitHub would be ideal. It's really hard to get anything from these short snippets.